# Adding items to Cache Storage Management

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, holepunching

I'm using FPC with redis.  I'd like to be able to flush the homepage or category pages from this page.  How to I add these items to the Cache Storage Management?  Hole punching?  But how do I link the hole punching to the Cache Storage Management?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the items shown there are the cache items available. Since homepage and category pages are in FPC you can't display them separately.

This would require you to add a custom cache item.[This tutorial](http://magento-hackernotes.blogspot.nl/2013/08/magento-how-to-cache-custom-data-into.html#.VYgYdt_0-pc) explains how. Basically you need to define it in a custom modules `config.xml`

```
<global>
    <cache>
        <types>
             <[custom_cache_name]module="[namespace]_[module]" translate="label description">
                <label>Custom cache</label>
                <description>A custom cache</description>
                <tags>[CUSTOM_CACHE_TAG]</tags>
             </[custom_cache_name]>
        </types>
    </cache>
</global>
```

and then write an observer that displays and one that saves the output of a whole page to that cache

Fetching it would be something like

```
$isActive = Mage::app()->useCache('[namespace]_[module]');
if ($isActive) {
    // Cache is active
    $cacheId = 'YOUR_CACHE_' . Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() . '_homepage';
    if ($cacheContent = Mage::app()->loadCache($cacheId)) {
       return $cacheContent;
    }
}

// if not active or no content render page as normal
```

But stuff like normal FPC hole punching etc is missing here. It would basically require you to completely rebuild an FPC module.

Another option would be to find a way to check which cache IDs are homepage or category page and make a script that removes those with

`Mage::app()->removeCache([some_cache_id]);`

Comment: Where would I call this removeCache method?

Comment: some custom written script you call. How you want to do that is up to you. It can be a shell script or a controller in the backend that executes the code

Comment: So i'd have to disable FPC for homepage and category pages and add those pages (like above) to my custome defined cache?

Comment: Yup, but I wouldn't advice something like that. It's a lot of work if you get it to work at all

Comment: Okay thanks, i'm just trying to determine a way to flush these sections individually while keeping things like FPC functional.

Comment: I'd probably contact the developer and ask him what he would recommend. There might be unforeseen issues you would run into that he knows about

Comment: hmm.. okay. So you don't think it's possible to flush these individual sections while keeping them within FPC?

Comment: I'm not sure, that will be different per FPC module